# What happens to Gmail emails after a hosting change?

Tags: email, gmail

I am hosting the email for one of my domains at Gmail.  I then run an IMAP client on my local computer to read and send email.  Totally standard.

I now want to move the hosting for that domain to another email provider, where I will again run an IMAP client to deal with the mail.

Question: What happens to all the messages that are currently on Gmail?  I THINK that they will stay in place, and I'll be able to access them via gmail.com and/or a Gmail app.  But maybe not?  Maybe Gmail will somehow find out about the MX change and decide that it should delete them all, because Reasons.  Or it can't find the messages on its own server because the MX has changed, and so won't let me see them.  Or something.  In any case, losing access to these old messages would be Very Bad.

So, which is it? Will the world behave the way that I'm 99% sure that it will, such that I'll still be able to go to gmail.com and read the old messages after the switch?  Or do I need to move the old messages somewhere else before making the hosting switch?  Thanks for helping with my paranoia!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google doesn't care what domain you use to route emails towards your Gmail inbox.  If you change your domain to use another email provider, you will still have your existing Gmail inbox, until you shut down your Gmail account.  So any existing emails in your Gmail inbox will be left untouched.

The same goes for any other hosting provider.

Comment: Thanks for calming my paranoia!